# The History of Muktzeh

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, muktzeh

Where can I find information on muktzeh from an historical perspective? I would like to get a sense as to what different tannaim and amoraim considered to be muktzeh (both for Shabbes and for yontef), but also a spread of responses from rishonim and acharonim on the matter.

Comment: I would recommend the Encyclopedia Talmudit.